# SP 2013 Workflow: Update a property with an incremental value?

Tags: workflow, designer

I have a Document Library with an associated Workflow in SP 2013.
The workflow runs fines.

I have a property in my DL called "Modified Count"

I try to increment this value every time the WF runs.

I use the "Update Item in Current Item" action in the WF.
If I click on Current Item under List I choose "Current Item"
I can then set the "Modified Count" to a specific number but is it possible to set it to its current number + 1?

I try to enter "(Modified Count) + 1" in "Value Assignment" but it says "Please enter a number"

Thanks
P

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how you are trying to add but you need to use "Calculate" action to do arithmetic operations in WF. May be that's what you are looking for

Answer (score 0):

As Akshay mentioned, I used the Do a Calculation action in the Workflow. It seems to work nicely. Here are some details:

I created the Modified Count column as a Single Line of Text data type. It might work as a Number, but I didn't test that. I set the default value of the column to "0".

I created the workflow to only run when an item is changed. It's a little bit weird in that it waits for the document to be unlocked for editing before completing, but with a standard Check Out/Check In process, I don't see you running into many problems.

Here is a picture of the workflow I tested:
[image]

I hope this helps! :)